# 'HttpURLConnection' does not contain a definition for 'GetInputStream'

Tags: c#, android, httpurlconnection

I want to check the internet is available or not in my c#.net code for Android phone.

I used below codes but when I use the connection of `HttpURLConnection`, the `GetInputStream` is missed([getinputstream not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAGKu.jpg)) and I can't find it in list of "conn" methods.

I get below error next of build the project

> HttpURLConnection' does not contain a definition for
> 'GetInputStream'...

```
try
{
    String link = "http://www.google.com"; URL url = new URL(link) ;
    HttpURLConnection conn =   (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();
    conn.GetInputStream();
}
catch (Java.IO.IOException error)
{
    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, error.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

I googled about this issue but i can't any thing.

please guide me...

Comment: You need to convert Java to c#.  You get a response.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa5bb2bb-4cc8-41e8-ae15-45c2d7111c3d/j-to-c-conversion?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: why should I convert j# to C#? I havn't any problem in programming language

Comment: HttpURLConnection is a java method not a c# method.

Comment: I think your whole question is wrong. Are you programming in Java instead and really mean that you are having issues with your Java code for an Android application?

Comment: thanks for yor comments. yes,HttpURLConnection  is a class and GetInputStream is  its java method.I am programming in vs2015 with xamarin for Android Apllication.I use c# code and JDK 7.as I told I didn't see GetInputStream as method for  HttpURLConnection . @peter-stacey